# Parameter name Information missing in system view PG_PROC_INFO.proargnames for not named parameters

Tags: amazon-redshift

Creating a procedure including an unnamed parameter will not result in the PG_PROC_INFO.proargnames for that containing an empty string for that parameter.

This does not comply with the description of the proargnames column the in PostgreSQL documentation 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/catalog-pg-proc.html.

Anyone know if this is intentional or not?

**Example**
Defining  procedure using the following parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testunnamed (IN INTEGER, IN p2 INTEGER)
```

gives the following value for proargnames.

- PostgreSQL:  **{"","p2"}**
- Redshift:   **{"p2"}**

For redshift the same value is in both the View PG_PROC_INFO as well as the Table PG_PROC.

The information Is needed to generate the "(IN INTEGER, IN p2 INTEGER)" from data in PG_PROC_INFO. In postgreSQL there is a function pg_get_function_arguments that is not available in redshift.

**CAUSE - Driver issue**
As I did begin to suspect this being a driver issue (Running with  RedshiftJDBC 01.02.27.1051 )
I did test by running a connection to Redshift using the PostgreSQL driver instead.
That seem to be spot on. I now get the expected output.

`SELECT  p.proname, p.pronargs, p.proargnames  FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc_info p 
       WHERE p.proname  LIKE 'testunnamed%' ;`

```
Driver       proname       pronargs   proargnames 
-------      -----------   --------   ----------- 
PostgresSQL  testunnamed   2          {"","p2"}   
Redshift     testunnamed   2          {"p2"}
```

Comment: What is your issue/challenge/question? Redshift <> Postgres (including v8)

Comment: Thanks, Just added the this last in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your results. Can you provide the queries you used to get `{"p2"}`?

```
SELECT version();
--  … Redshift 1.0.7804

CREATE PROCEDURE testunnamed (IN INTEGER, IN p2 INTEGER) language plpgsql as $$ begin null; end; $$;
-- CREATE PROCEDURE

SELECT proargnames FROM pg_proc_info WHERE proname = 'testunnamed';
--  proargnames
-- -------------
--  {"",p2}

SELECT proargnames FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'testunnamed';
--  proargnames
-- -------------
--  {"",p2}
```

Comment: I use the same query as you (adding some more columns).
I have tested using clients DbVisualizer, Datagrip and https://app.us.datarow.com/. Thanks for putting me on this trail. It made me find out the root cause. The driver. See the updated question

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the JDBC driver has been fixed in the latest version of the driver.